# MPMusicPlayerController play not working with Apple Music

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

I am using the new Apple Music API with MPMusicPlayerController but play method doesn't work in the first time called, but after the second or third time.

My code is the following:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *appleMusicPlayer = /*access instantiated player*/;
[appleMusicPlayer setQueueWithStoreIDs:@[url]];
[appleMusicPlayer play];
```

The player is instantiated as follows:

```
_appleMusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
_appleMusicPlayer.repeatMode = MPMusicRepeatModeNone;
_appleMusicPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleModeOff;
[_appleMusicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

The url passed in setQueueWithStoreIDs method is a NSString with a country-specific valid iTunesID. I provide you with a screenshot of NSLog output of url after above play method is called.

[image: NSLog]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ps. all player method calls are called on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure url is a string of the store ID!

You can get that here: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Comment: All urls passed are country specific storeID strings.

Comment: What do you mean `country-specific storeID`? Doesn't song id unique for the all country?

Comment: It works after the first time so it can't be related to country specific restrictions.